# How to get Google search results' snippet using ajax API?

Tags: ajax, google-api, code-snippets

I'm using one example code from StackOverflow to get the search results' title, URL and snippet:

```
for (int s = 0; s < 20; s = s + 4)
{
    String address = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=" + s + "&q=";
    String query = "ucd";
    String charset = "UTF-8";

    URL url = new URL(address + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset));
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
    GoogleSearch results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleSearch.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Title: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(i).getTitle().replaceAll("<b>", "").replaceAll("</b>", ""));

        System.out.println("URL: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(i).getUrl());

        System.out.println("Snippet: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(i).getSnippet() + "\n");

        System.out.println(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(i));
    }
}
```

But it seems that the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q= does not return the snippet from search.

Any other ways using Google API to get this? Can't find one after search...

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `getContent()` rather than `getSnippet()`. For example:

```
System.out.println("Snippet: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(i).getContent() + "\n");
```